# How to display a file into jtable

Tags: jtable

I have a Time table file and I would like to display it using Jtable. Also I would lik to make an Event ,so when I click on Timetable button I get my Time table?? Thanx

Comment: Any help how to do it??

Answer (score 0):

You could make your own Jtable with the following code:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/SimpleTableDemoProject/src/components/SimpleTableDemo.java

You can change table column names in the code:

```
String[] columnNames = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Sport",
                        "# of Years", "Vegetarian"};
```

You can set and store data on each column:

```
Object[][] data = {
    {"Kathy", "Smith",
     "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
    {"John", "Doe",
     "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Sue", "Black",
     "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
    {"Jane", "White",
     "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
    {"Joe", "Brown",
     "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
};
```

I wondering, why you want to get your timetable when clicking on it? To edit data on the column?

Comment: I have a timetable file already and I want when I click on the button the file will display?? but I still can't get it to work??

Comment: Which button are you talking about? You opened up the java application windows of the SimpleTableDemo?

Comment: Did you compile and run SimpleTableDemo.java file and get the java application windows of the SimpleTableDemo?

Comment: When you compile the java file, open up Windows command prompt. Move your homedirectory to where the 'SimpleTableDemo.java' file is and use this statement 'javac -cp . SimpleTableDemo.java'. When running the compiled file, move your homedirectory to upper folder (ex. components) and use the statement 'java -cp . components/SimpleTableDemo'. Then you could get timetable windows.

Comment: I am working on my project which need when I click on timetable Event the table will display. I want to read the file to display it but I don't know how??

Comment: @user3274585 please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order we can see which button you're talking about. Also please show some effort in trying to solve it. Stack Overflow isn't a code factory. eseol has already given you a nice link to the documentation, where you can learn a lot. Please check it.